# Cloud build not working for different environment angular

Tags: angular, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

Below command, I am trying to run with cloud build trigger but it still picks up the enviroment.ts file

cloudbuild.yaml

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
  args: [ run, build, --configuration=Staging ]
```

Below is the Package.json script code

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"}
```

File replacement code from angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "projectname": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/projectname",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/css/style.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "8mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "staging": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "8mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "8mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "projectname:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "projectname:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "projectname:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "projectname-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "projectname:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "projectname:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "projectname",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "51d20bdf-c925-4ff9-b30c-d7fe27412dc1"
  }
}
```

Can you please help me where I am getting this wrong? I tried it with --prod as well but does not work, it always takes the evironment.ts file. However, it works fine when I do it locally. I see cloud build has the substitution variable concept not sure the best way of using it.

**EDIT**

Even If I have the below-staging command in cloud build it just takes the *ng build* always. refer to the image.
I do not see any errors everything is successful.

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
  args: [ run, build, --configuration=staging ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change cloudbuild.yaml to below

```
steps:

- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
  args: [ install ]


- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
  args: ['run', 'build','--','--prod']

- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ['app', 'deploy', '--version=$SHORT_SHA']
```

Replace `--prod` to `--configuration=staging` if you want it for environment other than prod

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the `fileReplacements` in the `build` object as well (this one is used for `ng serve`).

```
  "build": {
    "options": {
      [...]
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
      ]      
    },
    "configurations": {
      // other - non default - configurations 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please check the angular.json file I have added full JSON file.

Comment: Could you please share which version of Angular you are using?

Comment: I am using Angular 7

Comment: I Was able to see that you added the File Replacements for each environment, are you getting any errors? or any relevant logs in Cloud Build?

Comment: No errors. But I observed below things for cloud build -- 
If I add below step to cloudbuild.yaml
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
  args: [ run-script, build, --configuration=staging ]
it takes just not the staging thing
build
refer below image In my edit section

Answer (score -1):

Create a file in environment folder called `environment.staging.ts` and use the below command

```
ng build --configuration=staging
```

Comment: I already have it. Did you read my question I am talking about cloud build!
i.e. I am having those commands in cloudbuild.yaml file, which do not allow ng.